# FILTER ARRAYFORMULA with Dynamic Criteria

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

Here's my data.

```
[C]                 [D]        [E]  [F]                 [G]
Timestamp           Submitter  Year Song                Artist
11/15/2020 8:42:57  A          2005 Feel Good, Inc.     Gorillaz
11/16/2020 19:08:13 B          2005 Feel Good, Inc.     Gorillaz
11/15/2020 9:33:01  C          2005 The Hand That Feeds Nine Inch Nails
11/15/2020 19:59:22 D          2005 The Hand That Feeds Nine Inch Nails
```

Here's what I'm trying to do. Basically, I need to pull the timestamp from the 2nd time someone submitted a song. Seems like it should be doable, but the code below only produces a single row. Is there a way to make this work properly as an array formula?

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( SMALL( FILTER( C2:C, E2:E & F2:F & G2:G = E2:E & F2:F & G2:G), 2) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was much easier than I was imagining. I just needed a helper column in Column C to count up the instances of the song, like so:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F<>"",COUNTIFS(F2:F&G2:G&H2:H,F2:F&G2:G&H2:H,ROW(F2:F),"<="&ROW(F2:F)),""))
```

...then an ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP()) to pull the 2nd timestamp value for each song:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(G2:G<>"",VLOOKUP(F2:F&G2:G&H2:H&2,{F2:F&G2:G&H2:H&C2:C,D2:D},2,0),""))
```

Not sure how it could have been done in one go, though, so if you know a way, please do chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following without a helper column.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(E2:E&F2:F&G2:G),{SORT({E2:E&F2:F&G2:G,C2:D},2,1)},{2,3},0))
```

[image]

Comment: I had something like this at one point, but the problem is that I need the 2nd smallest value, not the smallest.

For context, I'm trying to get duplicate songs to appear in a list in a consistent order so that I can write in replacements in the columns to the right. Ordering by the 2nd timestamp for instances 1 and 2, then the regular timestamp for any further ones does the trick. I've got it working with the helper column (in fact, a whole separate helper sheet).

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding something this simple approach should work:

```
=ArrayFormula(FILTER(C2:C,C2:C<>"",COUNTIFS(E2:E&F2:F&G2:G,E2:E&F2:F&G2:G,ROW(E2:E),"<="&ROW(E2:E))=2))
```

This assumes that dates *per song* (i.e., not necessarily among *all* songs) are entered chronologically.

Essentially, you are filtering in all non-blank entries where the COUNT(IFS) as of each row is equal to 2 (i.e., the second mention of that year/song/artist).

Comment: Sorry it took me a while to check this. Problem is that it doesn't return a value for every row. I need the 2nd timestamp to be returned for every row of a given song. Thanks, though.

Comment: I know that what you are saying makes sense to you. But that is only because you can see everything, both in your sheet and in your head. From "out here," I still don't have a clear idea of what you are trying to do. The best way to get accurate, efficient help is to share a link to a sheet that has a set of realistic data and someplace where you manually type in your expected results. If you share such a link back here, you'll have the best chance at someone being able to help you.